# Using 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' on Client Web Part page

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, app-part

Can anyone tell me how I can use:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction, "sp.js");
```

in my Client Web Part pages (App Parts)?

In my standard pages it loads fine but when I try use this function in an app part page I keep getting an undefined error:

[image]

What resource/script do I need to load on the page to get this function to work?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and this worked for me

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', myFunction);
```

Make sure you add a reference to init.js script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
```

I have not tried the following, but it should work after loading init.js

```
SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have though that it would be in either the SP.js or the SP.Core.js file (although I can't confirm for definite). But have you tried:

`SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction, "sp.js");`

Comment: Yes, I tried that immediately after posting the question. Exact same error. If I inspect the SP object, it exists but SP.SOD is undefined. Really frustrating as it's hard to find documentation around this in the context of App Parts.